# How to Instantiate Golang Generic Type Seeding it From Reflect Type

Tags: go, generics, reflection

Having a generic interface

```golang
type G[T any] interface {
...
}
```

and `reflect.Type` `t`, how to instantiate another `reflect.Type` which would represent actually `G[t]`

Eventually the `t` it self should be matched against `G[t]`

```golang
func ImplementsG(t reflect.Type) bool {
    var gType reflect.Type = ... // get Type of exact interface G[of exact t]

    return t.Implements(gType)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your use case?  Go is statically compiled and so you shouldn't need to dynamically determine whether a type implements an interface.

Comment: I don't think you can do that in Go. You can't create an object without concrete type, and interface is not a concrete type. CMIIW, you are trying to build something like Java's proxy, right? (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html)

Comment: @JauharArifin instantiate(G, t) is not about to create an object yet it to get an exact specific type from generic interface `G[T any]` so that it would be  `exact G[exact t]`

Comment: @erik258. The use case is a general `func Clone[T any](value T) T`. It should create an instance of the same type (with a regular New) yet before it checks whether type can clone it self (implements `Cloneable[T]` interface). Cloneable should clone it self as `func(t T) Clone() T` not just to an abstract `interface{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to check it manually via reflection. Check out the example:

```golang
type Merger[T any] interface {
    Merge(override T) (T, error)
}

func asMerger(
    value reflect.Value,
) (
    mergeFn func(override reflect.Value) (reflect.Value, error),
    isMerger bool,
) {
    vType := value.Type()
    for i := 0; i < vType.NumMethod(); i++ {
        method := vType.Method(i)
        if method.Name != "Merge" {
            continue
        }
        methodType := method.Type
        if methodType.NumIn() != 2 {
            return nil, false
        }
        if methodType.NumOut() != 2 {
            return nil, false
        }
        if methodType.In(1) != vType {
            return nil, false
        }
        if methodType.Out(0) != vType {
            return nil, false
        }
        if methodType.Out(1) != reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem() {
            return nil, false
        }
        return func(override reflect.Value) (merged reflect.Value, err error) {
            // call method
            results := method.Func.Call([]reflect.Value{value, override})
            if !results[1].IsZero() && !results[1].IsNil() {
                err = results[1].Interface().(error)
            }
            return results[0], err
        }, true
    }
    return nil, false
}
```